# How to navigate to and change value in XML config file with Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I am attempting to change *Value UseFunction="false" Value="Production"* to *Value UseFunction="false" Value="Training"* in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ParametersInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ParameterGroup TestRequired="false" Name="CommonSystemConfig" xmlns="http://www....">
        <Parameter Name="DefaultEnvironmentId" Text="DefaultEnvironmentId" ParameterType="List">
          <Value UseFunction="false" Value="Production">
            <ValueList>
              <string>Production</string>
              <string>Training</string>
              <string>Staging</string>
            </ValueList>
          </Value>
          <AutoSetValue UseFunction="false" Value="Production" />
          <IsUppercaseInput>false</IsUppercaseInput>
          <Description>The value can only be "Production" or "Training" or "Staging"</Description>
          <IsSetSuccessfully>true</IsSetSuccessfully>
          <Visible Type="0" Value="True" />
          <IsReadOnly Type="0" Value="False" />
          <AllowEmpty Type="0" Value="True" />
        </Parameter>
```

I was provided a script by u/Mathias R. Jessen, but then I noticed that I made some mistakes in my post and had to delete it. Here is where I am now, but the value is not being changed in the target XML file:

```
# load xml document from disk
$xmlFilePath = 'c:\Userdata\ParamBkUp.xml'
$rootedPath = Convert-Path $xmlFilePath

$xmlDoc = [xml]::new()
$xmlDoc.Load($rootedPath)

$nodesToChange = $xmlDoc |Select-Xml -XPath '//ParametersInfo/ParameterGroup[@Name="CommonSystemConfig"]/Parameter[@Name="DefaultEnvironmentId"]/Value[@Value="Production"]'

foreach($result in $nodesToChange){
    # update the Value attribute on the discovered `Value` nodes
    $result.Node.SetAttribute('Value', 'SomeOtherEnvironmentName')
}

# save changes to disk
$xmlDoc.Save($rootedPath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue with previous posting, but it was closed.  Here is a solution with PowerShell and xml linq

> 

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$Filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($Filename)

$descendants = $xDoc.Descendants()

$AutoSetValue = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($descendants, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x.Name.LocalName -eq "AutoSetValue"})
Write-Host "AutoSetValue = " $AutoSetValue
$AutoSetValue.SetAttributeValue("Value","Training")
Write-Host "AutoSetValue = " $AutoSetValue
```

Here is code that should solve your issue

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$Filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($Filename)

$descendants = $xDoc.Descendants()

$DefaultEnvironmentId = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($descendants, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) ($x.Name.LocalName -eq "Parameter") -and ([string]$x.Attribute("Name").Value -eq "DefaultEnvironmentId")})
Write-Host "DefaultEnvironmentId = " $DefaultEnvironmentId
$AutoSetValue = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($DefaultEnvironmentId.Descendants(), [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x.Name.LocalName -eq "AutoSetValue"})
Write-Host "AutoSetValue = " $AutoSetValue
$AutoSetValue.SetAttributeValue("Value","Training")
Write-Host "AutoSetValue = " $AutoSetValue
```

Comment: Thanks.  The xml that I provided is just an excerpt from a very large file with many parametergroups.  I should have been more clear, am looking for way to identify a specific value and change it based on it's attribute name (and once working I am hoping to apply the method to other values in the same XML).  Mathias' solution makes sense to me but it is not changing desired value. Is there a way to validate that anything is selected with: $xmlDoc |Select-Xml -XPath '//ParametersInfo/ParameterGroup[@Name="CommonSystemConfig"]/Parameter[@Name="DefaultEnvironmentId"]/Value[@Value="Production"]'

Comment: A path is not very useful.   I only gets one path and not a group.  Usually you need to change more than one item.  You can put a string into Descendants to get groups of elements or use Local Name like I did above.  there is no reason you can't get a descendant in one step and the get the children of the descendant in a second step.

Comment: Ok Thanks.  There are 270 "AutoSetValue"'s in the XML file... How can I narrow it down to the specific one that I am looking to modify?

Comment: Either you need to change all of them, or something else is needed to identify the node (sub branch of the xml), or just the ones that have Production as old value.

Comment: I updated code to get the correct AutSetValue.

Comment: Thanks JDWeng.  It now appears to be targeting the correct section (based on powershell Write-host but there are no changes made to the XML file.  Am I missing something to make it commit the changes?

Comment: You have to add : $xDoc.Save($outputFilename).  Use a different filename from input so you do not change the original file.